# Método Jump(Pulo) com mais de uma sequência de animação

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity-5

Amigos eu estou mexendo com a animação de pulo de um personagem e esta animação tem duas sequências, uma de quando andando, outra correndo:

```
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && liberaPulo == true && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            heroiRB.AddForce(new Vector2(0, force), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            PuloLateral();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && liberaPulo == true && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            heroiRB.AddForce(new Vector2(0, force), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            PuloLateral();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && liberaPulo == true && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) 
        {
            heroiRB.AddForce(new Vector2(0, force), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            anim.SetBool("PuloLateral", true);
            anim.SetBool("Andar", false);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && liberaPulo == true && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            heroiRB.AddForce(new Vector2(0, force), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            anim.SetBool("PuloLateral", true);
            anim.SetBool("Andar", false);
        }
```

Eu queria criar um método void PuloLateral(){} para deixar mais organizado, mas encontrei uma certa dificuldade ao tentar isso, já que tem duas sequências, correndo e andando. É possível deixar essas duas sequências no mesmo método de PuloLateral()? Tentei com um teste If e não consegui o resultado, apenas o pulo correndo funciona:

```
    void PuloLateral()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && liberaPulo == true && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && liberaPulo == true && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)))
    {
        anim.SetBool("PuloLateral", true);
        anim.SetBool("Correr", false);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && liberaPulo == true && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && liberaPulo == true && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        anim.SetBool("PuloLateral", true);
        anim.SetBool("Andar", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual é exatamente o problema?

Comment: O problema é que a animação de PuloLateral não está sendo executada quando o personagem pula andando, mesmo estando tudo certo no Animator, então para organizar melhor as animações eu queria criar um método para elas. 
No caso do método de PuloLateral criada daquele jeito que passei, continua não funcionando a animação, acredito ter algo de errado com o método que eu não esteja percebendo.

Comment: Olá. Você depurou (debugou)? Tem certeza que esse código tá certo? Pergunto porque me parece muito estranho o código do método `PulaLateral` ter duas condições que fazem *exatamente* a mesma coisa (que é ligar a variável `PuloLateral` e desligar a variável `Andar`).

Comment: Então Luiz, pela aba do Animator da Unity dá para ver se a ação está sendo executada quando pressionado as tais teclas, e lá está tudo ok, o estranho é que não executa a animação.
Perdão, não sei se entendi bem mas uma é transição para Correr (tecla de andar + shift apertado) e outra para Andar (sem shift).
Passei o projeto para meu professor do curso de games e ele achou estranho não estar executando também pois aparenta estar tudo ok com o Animator, disse que quando tiver tempo vai dar uma olhada melhor.
Eu estou desconfiando de algum bug com a própria engine

Comment: Oi. Demorei pra responder porque vc não me marcou (com @) no seu comentário, então não vi até hoje. Tá, mas eu perguntei se vc depurou o seu código. Ele tá entrando no código que vc espera que ele entre? É difícil te ajudar sem detalhes mais específicos. Se vc fizer um exemplo mínimo que reproduza o problema e subir ele em algum lugar pra eu baixar, eu posso testar e tentar te ajudar.

Comment: @LuizVieira Opa Luiz perdão, os estudos andam corridos. Eu havia sim depurado e estava entrando normal só não estava executando mesmo, meu professor deu uma olhada e realmente é um probleminha na versão da Unity que eu estava utilizando (2017.3.1f1) ela está com alguns probleminhas, baixei uma versão de junho de 2017 e tá resolvido, obrigadão pela atenção viu!